# How to append values to this.events

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've tried everything and I can't get this to work, not sure what I'm doing wrong...

I have an array items to pass to a rest provider... all it does is returns the result of the query

How do I get it store the values and append the new values to the this.events?? Obviously, at the moment it only returns the info for test 3

Events is declared as events: Observable;

```
var arrInfoToFetch = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"];

for (let i = 0; i < arrInfoToFetch .length; i++) {
  this.events = this.rest.getInfo(searchDate,arrInfoToFetch[i]);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add 

events: Observable<any>;

Comment: If `this.events` is an array then just use `this.events.push()`

Comment: it's not an array

Answer (score 0):

First of all please note the extra space in your code: `arrInfoToFetch .length` fix it to:

```
var arrInfoToFetch = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"];

for (let i = 0; i < arrInfoToFetch.length; i++) {
  this.events = this.rest.getInfo(searchDate,arrInfoToFetch[i]);
}
```

Second, the event is only returning three because, your events are being assigned with the current value in the array:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < arrInfoToFetch.length; i++) {
      this.events = this.rest.getInfo(searchDate,arrInfoToFetch[i]);
    }
```

`events` will always contain the value of `Test 3`.
What you should do is, create a new array and push the result inside.

```
 var arrInfoToFetch = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"];
 var arrInfoRecieved = new Array(arrInfoToFetch.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < arrInfoToFetch.length; i++) {
      arrInfoRecieved.push(this.rest.getInfo(searchDate,arrInfoToFetch[i]));
    }
```

---

**Edit for comment of `observable<any>`**:

```
 var arrInfoToFetch = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"];
        for (let i = 0; i < arrInfoToFetch.length; i++) {
          this.events
            .fromEvent(this.rest.getInfo(searchDate,arrInfoToFetch[i]))
            .map(() => [arrInfoToFetch.length]) 
            .scan((list, items) => list.concat(items), [])
            .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
        }
```

Comment: but then how do i get this.events to hold arrInfoRecieved if this.events is observable <any>;

Comment: Thanks! Next issue is the .fromEvent, i'm getting an error that it cant be accessed. How do i declare this? I tried import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

Comment: You need to import `'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent' `